# expected expression error compiling GPU kernel on NVIDIA GPU

Tags: opencl, nvidia, pyopencl

I get the following problem if I try to run my OpenCL kernel on a server with and NDIVA GPU,
On my mac there is no problem.
It is this line of code that seems to be the problem,

```
float largest_0 = max(float (sin_i_angle), float (cos_i_angle));
```

Here is the error message.

```
  File "threed_dp.py", line 918, in gpu_calculate_segment_costs_orig
    bld = prg.build()
  File "/work/mrdrygal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 510, in build
    options_bytes=options_bytes, source=self._source)
  File "/work/mrdrygal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 554, in _build_and_catch_errors
    raise err
pyopencl._cl.RuntimeError: clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE - clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE - clBuildProgram failed: BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE

Build on <pyopencl.Device 'Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB' on 'NVIDIA CUDA' at 0x3767e50>:

<kernel>:82:33: error: expected expression
          float largest_0 = max(float (sin_i_angle), float (cos_i_angle));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float (sin_i_angle)
```

Is not a valid expression in C. It is valid in C++ (explicitly invoking an instructor on `float()`), so perhaps that is why Apple's OpenCL compiler is allowing it. You should change the line to:

```
float largest_0 = max((float)sin_i_angle, (float)cos_i_angle);
```